# Scroll the Layout Editor in Android ADT Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

Has anyone figured out how to scroll the contents of the Layout Editor when those contents overflow one "screen"? I'm talking about at design-time while using the ADT Layout Editor, not scrolling at run-time on a physical device (that works fine).

Comment: I'm researching this and the problem is still happening with the newest version of Eclipse Helios (downloaded yesterday) and the latest ADT with API version 12. This really sucks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off clipping in android layout editor.

"toggle clipping" button is at the top-right corner in android layout editor

Hope this helps.

Comment: Finally got back to my Android project. I can't seem to locate that button. I see the Explode and Outline buttons but no Toggle Clipping button. Thanks!

Comment: its the very next button to the Outline button. ( it has no name on it)

- sorry no idea on posting a screen shot here easily.

Comment: thanks croc.. but its not working for me..
i have ADT 0.9.7 in eclipse..
It does not toggle..

any help ?

Comment: In ADT 10.0, the clipping option seems to have disappeared. So how do you work with ScrollView in ADT 10?

Comment: you can create a custom layout and make the width or height big enough to fit the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your API level to be more than 5, that will enable the toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but when editing a layout you want to use in a scroll editor, you can add "    android:layout_height="3000dp"

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="3000dp" >
```

This makes the layout in the editor very long, then when you are done you can switch it back to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the device type to a 10' tablet(layout editor top left 2nd option) made the screen big enough for me to fit everything in without having to scroll.
Do your thing and then revert to normal size.