# Android plugins (ADT) v10.0 lost the "clipping" toggle in the visual layout editor?

Tags: android, adt

In earlier versions of the ADT visual editor, there was an option to
toggle "clipping" of the contents of the layout; it was essential for
working with ScrollView layouts that had lots of child views, as it
let you see and manipuate ALL children instead of just what is visible
at the top of the ScrollView. (see [Scroll the Layout Editor in Android ADT Eclipse Plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814004/scroll-the-layout-editor-in-android-adt-eclipse-plug-in))
That option seems to have disappeared in ADT 10.0. Where has it gone?
How does one work with ScrollView and nested children in ADT 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android dev team comments in http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15892 the visual editor is supposed to show the entire contents of a ScrollView, but there are bugs. Hopefully a fix will be released soon, as it's nearly impossible to work with ScrollView in the editor as it is right now.

Comment: Well, this isn't working neither with the latest Eclipse nor with the latest ADT.

Comment: For all those like me who are still googling this, the problem still exists as of June 2012.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround I've discovered is to create a new device configuration and increase the vertical resolution enough to fit your view.  It's not as simple as clicking the missing Toggle Clipping button, but it works.

- Select **Custom...** from the dropdown of device configurations at the upper left of the layout editor
- Select an existing configuration and click the **Copy** button
- Select the **Portrait** row under the copy and click **Edit**
- Select the screen dimension from the list of **Chosen Qualifiers**.  The X and Y values will appear in text boxes to the right.
- Increase the larger dimension (defaults to 800 for the Nexus One) as needed, and then click **OK** to save.

Now, you can use the new custom device configuration to see your entire ScrollLayout.  If you do want to see what's "above the fold" on a particular device, just switch back to the original configuration.

Answer (score 0):

under Relativelayout of ScrollView, Assign Gravity of Layout Parameter to Center and Height to 2000dp(As required). This will make the Layout Huge and Centered. Now Play around with Margin Top to See Specific view of Scrollable Layout!